# Data can not be seen without reloading page during API call

Tags: angular, typescript

After login, the page route is navigated to "dashboard" where http:get api call is fetching data from the server. But it is not showing any data if the page is not reloaded. I have searched for many ways to solve that problem but nothing could solve my problem. Can anyone help me what I missed here or what I have to do get the data without reloading the page?

N:B: I am using Angular 7 as my frontend.

Comment: Please provide some sample code and/or upload something in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! We have no chance of helping you when you aren't sharing any code with us

Comment: @sayed-siam I echo what the other two users said. Folk are keen to help but we would need to see some code snippets please. As well as showing your code please share the routing that you have set up.

Answer (score 0):

you have two option to solve this issue

1. use local storage on the parent page.
2. use API call on the child page, 
              and only subscribe to the useful data.

I preferring the 2nd method because it's very effective,

steps:

1.from parent page to child page ,you need to pass the data.id or object.id

2.call API on child page, and filter the data with the passing data.id from the parent

so, if you reload the child-page, the child-page hit the API again and get the data and the id from the URL which help to filter the necessary data

```js
 //parent page
 //onclick parent page navigate to child page
 //data contain id,title,info etc....
 passData(data){
    this.newsService.blogData = data;
    this.router.navigate(['/child-page',data.id]);
  }
  
  
  
  
  //api service
export class NewsService {
  public blogData:any[]=[]; //array declare
  constructor ( private http: HttpClient){ }
  fetchNews(): Observable<Object> {
      return this.http.get('api-url'); 
  }


  
 // on child page
   fetchNews(){
    this.newsservie.fetchNews().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.newsList = data;
      this.readmorecontent = this.newsList[this.id];
      console.log(this.readmorecontent)
    });
```